# Returning data from API with joins

Tags: angularjs, laravel, api-design

I have created a basic API using Laravel and am currently building the front end with Angular. Something I am struggling to decide on is how / where to cross reference data in the form of id's with their actual value.

A task object is currently returned from the API as the following:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "task_owner":7,
   "client":2,
   "campaign":17,
   "created_by":1,
   "title":"Finalise agenda for Call.",
   "notes":null,
   "viewed":0,
   "priority":1,
   "start_date":"2016-08-10",
   "end_date":"2016-08-11",
   "sub_tasks":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "title":"my first subtask"
      }
   ]
}
```

When displaying the task - I obviously want to show actual values, not ID's, for client, campaign, created_by etc. But I also need the id's to update those tables later, and for filters (ie show only tasks where client_id = 2).

So should I cross reference and send back these bits of data and include as part of my task object - or should I pull all user, client and campaign data in separate API calls first, and then cross reference on the front end?

Comment: You should pull everything on one request. Eloquent will make joins and queries with eager loading so your MySQL requests will be minimum too.

Answer (score 0):

The Eloquent framework is a powerful tool when querying. I would use the `with()` function to include whatever you want to include.

```
Task::with('task_owner', 'campaign', 'created_by')->get();
```

This is requiring of course that the relationships is correctly set up in the Task model